# What libraries can I use to modify a video?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

I'm new to video processing and I'm wondering what libraries I can use to do things like detecting letters, drawing boxes around them and so on. If you can name me a couple of good ones, I'd appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**OpenCV**](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/): (Open Source Computer Vision) is a **cross-platform** library of programming functions for real time computer vision.

It provides interfaces for both C and C++ programming laguages.

As **for detecting the text region and drawing boxes around it**, you can take a look at [**this article**](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/), which explains how to do this stuff using OpenCV. **For better OCR capabilities** I think that [**tesseract**](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is the best open source tool available right now.

I've worked on a similar project some time ago and used OpenCV to detect the text region and then tesseract to do proper text recognition.